# How with jquery get checkbox input not selected in boolean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery 3.4.1 app I have checkbox defined

```
<div class="form-row mb-3 mt-3">
    <label for="step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-form-label">Invoice on next period</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" style="width: 50px;padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 7px;"
               id="step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx"
               checked>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I got valid true if checkbox input is selected. But I got undefined if checkbox input not is selected
and I need to set additive condition :

```
var step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx= $("#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx:checked").val()
if(typeof step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx=='undefined') step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx= false
```

Looks like it works ok, but if there is a better way to got valid true/false condition without additive
checking line ?

Thanks!

Comment: `if ( !step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx.prop( "checked" ) ) step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx= false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `prop`: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish based on the code, so here is some examples:

This code will take a checkbox that is checked and uncheck it for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx= $("#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx:checked");

    if (step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx.prop("checked")) {
        step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx.prop("checked", false);
    }
})
```

This code will take a checkbox that is not checked and do something

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx= $("#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx:checked");

    if (!step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx.prop("checked")) {
        //do something
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

This is the way you should go about doing this this way will listen for when the `checkbox` is checked (`true` or `false`) how it does this is by listening for the `checkbox` to be clicked when it is clicked it will run everything inside of `stepTwoInvoiceOnNextPeriodCbx.click()` what we are doing inside of the `stepTwoInvoiceOnNextPeriodCbx.click()` event is checking if the property `checked` is `true` or `false` (`stepTwoInvoiceOnNextPeriodCbx.prop("checked")`) if this is true in my code example we are going to change the text of the element with an `id` of `#text` to `"Is checked"` when `true` and `"is not checked"` when `false`.

### JavaScript

```js
let stepTwoInvoiceOnNextPeriodCbx = $(
  "#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx"
);
let text = $("#text"); // This is just here to show output of the example

// Listen for checkbox to be click
stepTwoInvoiceOnNextPeriodCbx.click(() => {
  // If the checked property
  if (stepTwoInvoiceOnNextPeriodCbx.prop("checked")) {
    // Is true set text to "Is checked"
    text.text("Is checked");
  } else {
    // Is false set text to "Is not checked"
    text.text("Is not checked");
  }
});
```

### HTML

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-row mb-3 mt-3">
    <label
      for="step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx"
      class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-form-label"
      >Invoice on next period</label
    >
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="1"
        style="width: 50px; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 7px;"
        id="step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx"
        checked
      />
    </div>
    <span id="text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is an example I made so you can see how it works https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-blackwell-d9hex?file=/src/index.js**

## What your code is doing

You are checking to see if the data type of the `value` property is `"undefined"`, `"undefined"` and `undefined` are two different things since you are checking the type of the data what you are telling the computer to do is check if the type of the `value` property is equal to (`==`) a `string` (text data type) with the value of `undefined` (`"undefined"`) this comparison is not checking the data types you would have to use the identical operator (`===`) this checks the value and data type are the same. the `val()` method get the `value` property of the `HTM`L element this in your case will always be `undefined` because it is never set.

The way you have coded this also means that it will only run once the page has loaded since you are not listening for a event (like `click()` in my example) the `click()` event means anytime the `#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx` element is clicked run the function inside of the `click()` event.

### Other things to keep in mind

In JavaScript, it is good practice to use camelcase for naming varibles and functions, not undersorces (snakecase) languages like `PHP` use snakecase (`this_is_snake_case`) while in JavaScript we use camelcase (`thisIsCamelCase`) but we tend use pascalcase (`ThisIsPascalCase`) for class names.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript

```
var isChecked = document.querySelector("#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx").checked;
```

jQuery

```
var isChecked = $("#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx").prop("checked");
```

---

`$("#step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx:checked")` gets you a HTML element with

1. id="step_2_invoice_on_next_period_cbx"
2. state "checked"

For an unchecked element the second condition is false and will return `undefined` for you.